# How to transfer PDF document from Lumia510 to my Laptop

Tags: lumia

How can I transfer my PDF documents from Nokia-lumia 510 to my laptop in order to print them. Thanks

Comment: Where do you see the file on your phone?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Microsoft's PDF Reader App](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=8f6154d6-1b70-431a-a579-b6a43477e837) you can share documents on OneDrive and then sync them back to your PC (or download them through OneDrive.com).